# How to achieve rows to columns from one data frame to another data frame in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

How to achieve this through pyspark using any of the functions to use in notebooks of Azure Synapse?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pivot + groupBy + agg()` function for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1234','VW','1022'),('1234','YH','5466'),('12345','VW','1022'),('12345','YH','5466')],['col1','col2','col3'])

df.groupBy("col1").pivot("col2").agg(first(col("col3"))).show(10,False)
#+-----+----+----+
#|col1 |VW  |YH  |
#+-----+----+----+
#|1234 |1022|5466|
#|12345|1022|5466|
#+-----+----+----+
```

---

If you need the output column names in specific format then use `toDF()` to change the column names.

```
df.groupBy("col1").pivot("col2").agg(first(col("col3"))).toDF("col1","col2=VW","col2=YH").show(10,False)
#+-----+-------+-------+
#|col1 |col2=VW|col2=YH|
#+-----+-------+-------+
#|1234 |1022   |5466   |
#|12345|1022   |5466   |
#+-----+-------+-------+
```